# Select a random point in the union of 2 hexagons

Tags: geometry

The goal is to find a random points in the intersection area of 2 hexagons. I am given the 6 coordinates points (x,y) of 2 hexagons. These 2 hexagons overlaps each other. How could I select a random point that reside in this intersection area?

[Here is some visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIAa3.png)

The intersection area can be of any shapes/size. The above picture is only 1 case.
My initial thought is to find the lines from the 12 points given. Then out of these lines, find which one of them intersects. These intersected lines will give me a brief understanding of the union region between these 2 shapes. However, I'm having trouble trying to do that. If anyone could point me to the most efficient method, that would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the hexagons convex? I assume the point needs to be chosen uniformly. You could find a bounding box, and select points from it until you find one that lies in both hexagons. That is not efficient, but it is simple. Or you could calculate the intersection region exactly, triangulate it, choose one of the triangles at random (weighted by area) and then choose a point uniformly from that chosen triangle.

Comment: Do you mean you're having trouble working out how to calculate whether the lines intersect? I wrote an answer about that but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: yes the hexagons are convex. I was thinking about the brute force approach. However, this would take a long time to converge if the area of the 2 hexagons are large and the union is small. About the second approach, could you elaborate?

Comment: If you just want to check if a point is within both hexagons, you only need to calculate the normals from the edges of the hexagons going either clockwise or anticlockwise.